# D3.JS unable to load very large .csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am creating force directed graph in D3.JS when I build it using dummy data it was build fine

Following is the code for it:

[My Force Directed Graph](http://plnkr.co/edit/LcuMPLxy8JRQSUUDo5HB?p=preview)

But when I am loading my original csv file(which contains very large rows >65535 actually). The graph is not loading.

What should I do so that it loads reads my csv file fast or atleast loads it in defined amount of time.

Comment: It sounds like the file is loading fine, but the visualisation is taking too long to render. A large number of nodes and links are a problem especially with the force layout. It sounds like in this particular case there's not a lot you can do apart from trying to show only parts of the graph.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff So wont it  change if I build the graph using json?

Comment: It doesn't sound like it, no. How many nodes/links do you have?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have around 1.5 lakh rows for nodes/links

Comment: That's not going to work. No browser will be able to display and animate this number of elements without problems.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff So is there any other way to solve this problem. or should I go with the approach of decreasing my data?

Comment: It sounds like decreasing the amount of data shown is the only option.

Comment: how did you solve this? and how did you decrease the data in d3?

Comment: @kjamp devise a mechanism to decrease the amount of data. We used it to display important data points.

Answer (score 0):

i was also face same problem but after more R&D found some reult , node.js becaue it run on server so it will load your all data very fast.and you can do you job.

Thank you